# select random COLUMN from PostgeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains some links to photos in a few columns and I need to get a random photo from it.

```
SELECT photo_front, photo_left, photo_rear FROM photos ORDER BY RANDOM () LIMIT 1
```

gives me a 3 links. But can I get only 1 random out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot.  For instance:

```
SELECT v.photo
FROM photos p CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (photo_front), (photo_left), (photo_rear)
     ) v(photo)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```

If the columns can ever be `NULL`, then you might want `WHERE v.photo IS NOT NULL`.

I should note that using `ORDER BY RANDOM()` is an expensive operation.  You are using that in your query and so performance does not seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
SELECT (array[photo_front, photo_left, photo_rear])[(random() * 2 + 1)::int] as random_phot
FROM photos 
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
```

`(random() * 2 + 1)::int` generates a random number between 1 and 3 and that is used to pick an element from the array (which contains the three columns)